# How can I display the Flickr API in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, flickr

I'm having trouble displaying and retrieving photos of restaurants/food from the [Flickr API](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=restaurants&format=json&jsoncallback=?).

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gnetags=restaurants&format=json&jsoncallback=?
```

I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly but here is my current code:

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
var flickerURL="http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne? 
tags=restaurants&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
$.getJSON(flickerURL)
  .done(function( data ) {
    $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
      $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
      if ( i === 11 ) {
        return false;
      }
     });
   });
})();
```

HTML:

```
<!--Display Photos-->

<section>
  <div class="images"> </div>
</section>
```

I am not receiving any errors alerts, however, the data is simply not displaying on the page.

Comment: please format your code and explain what kind of problems you have (errors ect... )

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon thank you, I have restructured my code. I am not seeing any error alerts on my page, however, the data is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Your image insertion code was not ok, you was inserting image on an id instead of a class. You should use the native DOM API for this stuff for better performance ect... If you wish to keep it like that juste replace `#images` by `.images`

```js
(function() {
  var flickerURL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=restaurants&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON(flickerURL)
    .done(function(data) {
      var div = document.querySelector('.images');
      data.items.slice(0, 10).map((item, index) => {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = item.media.m;
        img.onload = () => div.appendChild(img);
      });
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="images"> </div>
</section>
```